# Introduction of shape parameters in the formulation of probability distribution

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-physics, statistics, probability

I'm familiar with the definition of location, scale, and shape parameters, and the type of distributions they parametrized. I'm interested in understanding how shape parameters became part of the common set of parameters in use to commonly describe probability distributions and if there is any clear historical path that brought to their definition and use.

Comment: I think it was Karl Pearson, who was considered the founder of mathematical statistics. See wiki for all the details and list of his publications. Hope this helps!